# Failed to load resource after using API Key

Tags: javascript, fetch, openweathermap

I have this error "Failed to load resource: the server http://localhost:3000/api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=&appid=23012caa6cd9437d2588b8f412b67f5f responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

```
let baseURL = 'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=&appid=';
let apiKey = '23012caa6cd9437d2588b8f412b67f5f';
let newZip =  document.getElementById('zip').value;



document.getElementById('generate').addEventListener('click', performAction);
var feeling=document.createElement('DIV');
document.getElementById("feeling").appendChild(feeling);
function performAction(){
getWeather(baseURL,newZip, apiKey);
feeling.innerHTML=document.getElementById('feelingLabel').value;

}
async function getWeather (baseURL,newZip ,apikey){

  const res = await fetch(baseURL+newZip+apikey)
  try {

    const projectData = await res.json();
    
    console.log(typeof projectData);
   let date= document.createElement('DIV');
  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(date);
   let temp=document.createElement('Div');
   document.getElementById('container').appendChild(temp);
   let content=document.createElement('DIV');
   document.getElementById("container").appendChild(content);
   date.innerHTML=projectData[1];
   temp.innerHTML=projectData[2];
   content.innerHTML=projectData[3];
    return projectData;
  }  catch(error) {
    console.log("error", error);
    // appropriately handle the error
  }
}
```

Comment: You're just taking the parts and joining them together using "+", so the final URL will look like this: api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=&appid=<newZip><apiKey> (this is visible in the error message, too). Perhaps you need to put newZip in the id field, and apiKey in the appid field? Join the parts differently?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify any protocol in your `baseURL`, so the browser think you want to send a request to your own server (in your case `localhost:3000`) instead of to OpenWeatherMap. Try prepending either `https://` or `http://` to `baseURL`, like this:

```js
let baseURL = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=&appid=';
```

Comment: the error becomes 400 instead of 404(bad request)

Comment: That means that the request went to the proper place (OpenWeatherMap), but you didn't form your request correctly and the server rejected it. That's probably because you put the API key and the zip code after the URL, rather than after the `=` signs in the querystring.